# Como Borrar una tabla de SQLite Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

quiero borrar toda la tabla "TablaTodoItem" de la Base de datos, con un boton que esta al final de la Tabla.

```
 <CollectionView.Footer>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray">
                    <Button Text="Borrar Tabla de Pedidos" FontSize="14" TextColor="Red" FontAttributes="Bold" CornerRadius="20" WidthRequest="280" HeightRequest="50"
                            ContentLayout="Left,75" Image="Eliminar1"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                            Clicked="OnDeleteTablaAllClicked" />                
                    </StackLayout>
                </CollectionView.Footer>
```

evento del Boton

```
public async void OnDeleteTablaAllClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            bool accepted = await DisplayAlert("Borrar la tabla de pedidos es irreversible!!!!", "ESTÁS SEGURO?", "SÍ", "NO");

            if (accepted)
            {
                borrarTabla();

                
            }
        }
        public void borrarTabla()
        {
           PedidosDatabase.DeleteTablaAllAsync(TablaTodoItem, null, null);
        }
```

he intentado de multiples formas, pero no  me ha funcionado, al ejecutarse entra en interrupcion por error en el codigo.

Con esta opcion, me genera el error:

Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error   CS0119  'TablaTodoItem' es tipo, que no es válida en el contexto indicado   TRR C:\Users\evaqu\OneDrive\PROGRAMAS\APPS\TRR\TRR\TRR\Views\ListPedidos.xaml.cs    59  Activo

PedidosDatabase:

public class PedidosDatabase
{
static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;

```
    public static readonly AsyncLazy<PedidosDatabase> Instance = new AsyncLazy<PedidosDatabase>(async () =>
    {
        var instance = new PedidosDatabase();
        CreateTableResult result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<TablaTodoItem>();
        return instance;
    });

    public PedidosDatabase()
    {
        Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
    }
    public Task<List<TablaTodoItem>> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        return Database.Table<TablaTodoItem>().ToListAsync();
    }
    public Task<List<TablaTodoItem>> GetItemsNotDoneAsync()
    {
        return Database.QueryAsync<TablaTodoItem>("SELECT * FROM [TodoItem] WHERE [Done] = 0");
    }
    public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(TablaTodoItem item)
    {
        if (item.ID != 0)
        {
            return Database.UpdateAsync(item);
        }
        else
        {
            return Database.InsertAsync(item);
        }
    }

    public Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(TablaTodoItem item)
    {
        return Database.DeleteAsync(item);
    }

    public Task<int> DeleteTablaAllAsync(TablaTodoItem tablaTodoItem)
    {
        return Database.DeleteAsync(tablaTodoItem);
    }

}
```

Comment: Como que entra en interrupcion? Que error te da? coloca tu codigo y el error.

Comment: Que es PedidosDatabase ? puedes agregar como creas esta conexión?

Comment: DeleteAsync borra una fila, no una tabla... fijate bien en EF que metodo necesitas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución al inconveniente. No se si sea la mas conveniente, pero me funciono.
anexo los detalles de la solución encontrada.

en ListaPedidos.xaml.cs, para el boton de borrar tabla:

```
public async void DeleteTablaClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool accepted = await DisplayAlert("BORRAR tabla de pedidos y Terminar." +
            " Esta accion es IRREVERSIBLE!!", "¿ ESTÁS SEGURO ?", "SÍ", "NO");

        if (accepted)
        {

            var todoItem1 = (TablaPedidos)BindingContext;
            PedidosDBSQL database = await PedidosDBSQL.Instance;
            await database.DeleteTablaClicked(todoItem1);
            System.Environment.Exit(0);        
        }
    }
```

para la data correspondiente.

```
public Task<int> DeleteTablaClicked(TablaPedidos tablaPedidos)
    {
        return Database.DropTableAsync<TablaPedidos>();
        
    }
```